# Does exists Moqui documentation?

Tags: moqui

I am testing the moqui framework but i cant find documentation on internet about functional processes like organization setup, catalogs maintenance (products, accounts, people, customers, providers, etc), e-commerce administration, API integration, etc. Does this artifacts exists?

Comment: The only part of this that is relevant for Moqui Framework is the API integration, everything else is in other projects built on Moqui Framework including Mantle UDM and USL, SimpleScreens, and application components like PopCommerce. There is some information on API integration in the Making Apps with Moqui book, but that doesn't (yet) include the newer REST API functionality. Information is available for that but you have to dig a little.

Comment: On the functional business processes there is now significant OOTB functionality but as an OOTB usable application it is all very new (for the POP Commerce Admin app), and not even released yet. Somone has volunteered to write this and the work is already underway, but again it is very new and this takes some time to put together.